# Activemq degrade response time

Tags: spring, performance, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I`m using activemq 5.10 with spring 4.1.1.
I find a degrade problem with the response time of messages. After 4 days, the response time starts to grow up from 15ms to 200ms and more. 
The app works fine with approximately 1000 messages per second and then all run slower.

Here is part of the xml beans:

```
<amq:systemUsage>
            <amq:memoryUsage>
                <amq:memoryUsage limit="512 mb">
                </amq:memoryUsage>
            </amq:memoryUsage>
            <amq:storeUsage>
                <amq:storeUsage limit="50 mb"></amq:storeUsage>
            </amq:storeUsage>
            <amq:tempUsage>
                <amq:tempUsage limit="50 mb"></amq:tempUsage>
            </amq:tempUsage>
    </amq:systemUsage>

    <amq:broker brokerName="myBroker" id="broker"
        persistent="false" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true" enableStatistics="false"
        useLoggingForShutdownErrors="true">

        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector
                uri="nio://${Ip}:${Port}?jms.useAsyncSend=true?jms.useCompression=true"
                disableAsyncDispatch="false" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>

        <amq:destinationPolicy>
            <amq:policyMap>
                <amq:policyEntries>
                    <amq:policyEntry queue=">" optimizedDispatch="true" />
                </amq:policyEntries>
            </amq:policyMap>    
        </amq:destinationPolicy>

    </amq:broker>

    <!-- A JMS connection factory for ActiveMQ -->
    <bean id="ConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        p:brokerURL="nio://${Ip}:${Port}" />


    <bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="ConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
    </bean> 
<bean id="Listener" class="xx.com.xxx.MessageListener" />
<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
            connection-factory="ConnectionFactory" acknowledge="auto">
            <jms:listener destination="${QueueName}"
                ref="sisBusMessageListener" method="onMessage" />
 </jms:listener-container>
```

And here is the Java code:

```
public class MessageListener extends GenericMessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message request) {
        MyExecutor mythread = new MyExecutor(request, new DateTime());
        executor.execute(mythread );
    }
}
```

public class MyExecutor {

```
public void init() {
    try {
        connectionFactory = ApplicationHelper.getBean("ConnectionFactory");
        connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(false);
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logs...
    }
}  

public void returnMessage(Message request, Object responseFromExternalSystem) throws JMSException {

    MapMessage response = session.createMapMessage();
    response.setJMSCorrelationID(request.getJMSCorrelationID());

    //code that set info on map message is here

    replyProducer = session.createProducer(request.getJMSReplyTo());
    replyProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    replyProducer.send(response);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Increase your systemUsage values, especially storeUsage and tempUsage. Atleast double it.

Comment: Previusly I tried with the tempUsage= 300mb, storeUsage=128  and memoryUsage= 512mb but I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was re-use the connections and sessions creating only one instanace and creating an other instance in some cases(errors, desconnections...)